# Pipe "|" and brackets "[" being converted to "\|" and "\[" on Jekyll code block markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I want to display a block of code on a jekyll blog post. I'm using the following syntax:

```
{% highlight javascript %}
{% raw %}<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ site.google_analytics }}"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '{{ site.google_analytics }}');
</script>{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

However, on the resulting page the '|| []' caracters are converted to '\|| \[]'. Here is the rendered output showing that

[image]

How do I avoid this? Preferrably there should be a solution that didn't involve editing the code snippet itself.

Please do note that I'm already enclosing the code snippet with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error was that I should not use `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` when using the `{% highlight %}` tag.

This is the correct code:

```
{% highlight javascript %}
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ site.google_analytics }}"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '{{ site.google_analytics }}');
</script>
{% endhighlight %}
```